# How do I disable the left-(meta|windows) key binding in gnome-shell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell

I changed the keybinding to `Show the activities overview` in the panel `System Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts` to `Shift-ESC`, but the left-meta or left-windows key is still bringing it up.

How do I disable that binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 gconftool -s /apps/mutter/general/overlay_key -t string "Super_R"
```

worked (after shell restart) for me. Instead of `Super_R` feel free to put name of any key which doesn't exist on your keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

In recent GNOME use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

and to restore the default keybinding use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key 'Super_L'
```

*borrowed from [here](https://superuser.com/a/484688/25226).*

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: At **Tweak Tool** > **Typing** > **Alt/Win Key behavior**, select **Meta is mapped to Left Win**, this replaces the Left (but not right) Win key with a dummy alt key which otherwise works like the Win key but doesn't toggle Activities (and I saw that from Florence virtual keyboard).

Original answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/94929/629040).